# HTTP Adapter not working on real Android device-Mobilefirst platform

Tags: http, adapter, worklight-adapters

referring to my previous post.
[Using Worklight(MFP) HTTP Adapters with REST/JSON Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270185/using-worklightmfp-http-adapters-with-rest-json-services)
 To solve the issue i had to change the value of the host name in the mobilefirst development server from "localhost" to the ip address of my pc so that it works on the android emulator. While installing the .apk file on a real device it does not work. I think when i get the .apk, the ip address i set in the hostname(the ip of my pc) is applied in the

> /android/native/assets/wlclient.properties

```
wlServerProtocol = http
wlServerHost = 192.168.1.2 
wlServerPort = 10080
```

can i have some help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP address that is used by the client application is indeed controlled by the wlclient.properties file.

You can edit this file before building the .apk.

You can also:

1. Right-click on the MobileFirst application folder -> Run As -> Build Settings
2. Change the IP address
3. Build again

From now on, the IP address inside wlclient.properties will be the one you specified above in step 2.

Comment: Your answer is correct Idan. No doubt about it, can't it be fixed dynamically?

Comment: To change the server address during runtime you can use the API WL.App.setServerUrl / getServerUrl.

Comment: Thank you Idan. I follow your post on https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/02/02/changing-server-url-runtime/ .
It works fine on emulators but when i tried it on real android device it failed. The Url changed but it cannot connect to the server. I can't understand what is the issue. Thanks